# ERROR StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up. - Spark standalone cluster

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-submit, apache-spark-standalone

Spark job (Scala/s3) worked fine for few runs in stand-alone cluster with spark-submit but after few run it started giving the below error. There were no changes to code, it is making connection to spark-master but immediately application is getting killed with the reason “All masters are unresponsive! Giving up”.

```
22/03/20 05:33:39 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://spark-master:7077...
22/03/20 05:33:39 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to spark-master/xx.x.x.xxx:7077 after 42 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
22/03/20 05:33:59 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://spark-master:7077...
22/03/20 05:34:19 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://spark-master:7077...
22/03/20 05:34:39 ERROR StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
22/03/20 05:34:39 WARN StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Application ID is not initialized yet.
22/03/20 05:34:39 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 33139.
22/03/20 05:34:39 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on a1326e4ae4bb:33139
22/03/20 05:34:39 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
22/03/20 05:34:39 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://xxxxxxxxxxxxx:4040
22/03/20 05:34:39 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, a1326e4ae4bb, 33139, None)
22/03/20 05:34:39 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
22/03/20 05:34:39 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager a1326e4ae4bb:33139 with 1168.8 MiB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, a1326e4ae4bb, 33139, None)
22/03/20 05:34:39 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asking each executor to shut down
22/03/20 05:34:39 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, a1326e4ae4bb, 33139, None)
22/03/20 05:34:39 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, a1326e4ae4bb, 33139, None)
22/03/20 05:34:39 WARN StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Drop UnregisterApplication(null) because has not yet connected to master
22/03/20 05:34:39 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
22/03/20 05:34:39 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
22/03/20 05:34:39 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
22/03/20 05:34:39 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
22/03/20 05:34:39 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
22/03/20 05:34:40 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Can only call getServletHandlers on a running MetricsSystem
        at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:281)
```